# Does jquery mobile work with backbone marionette templates?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, marionette

I am having issues getting jquery mobile code to work with templates.  The results-region uses the results-template for the data.  Any ideas as to why jquery mobile stuff doesn't work or how do i get it to work?  I have has issues with the slide out panel as well.

```
<div id="results-region" data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="d" ></div>

<script type="text/template" id="results-template">
   <div data-role="collapsible">
      <h3><a href="#" data-rel="dialog"><%=faa%></a></h3>
      <p>testing</p>
   </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No issue using backbone with JQM.  You just need to call refresh after you dynamically add elements.

http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible-set/#method-refresh

```
$( "#results-region" ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );
```

Also something to be aware of.  You will not want extra divs wrapping your collapsible content.  In your result template you should remove the outer div and set the data-role programmatically in your itemView.

*edit: added a fiddle demonstrating a complete solution*

http://jsfiddle.net/puleos/naMMS/

[image]

Comment: How do i set the data-role programmatically in my itemView.  Sorry, im pretty new to backbone.

Comment: Thanks Scott but it still doesn't seem to be working.  My list items show up but not in the collapsable style.  Not sure whats wrong.  I also had issues with the jquery mobile panels acting this way too.

Comment: that is odd.  try and run $( "#results-region" ).collapsibleset( "refresh" ); from the console.  You may be calling it before the el has been added to the page.

Comment: Scott, looks like i still have an extra <div> before the collapsible content.  How do i get rid of this?  I thought removing the outter div in my result template would have done this.

Comment: Updated my answer with a fiddle.  Hopefully this is helpful.